# DRM content Netflix/Prime not playing in Ubuntu 22.04 ARM64

Tags: linux, arm, drm, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to play Netflix/Prime in Ubuntu 22.04 Arm64 architecture and getting the DRM error. I tried searching the web to install widevine but could not do so. Tried Chromium and Firefox browsers but no luck. Is it even supported for Arm64 architecture?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no Widevine ARM64 build available, so you're out of luck here.

There are ChromeOS builds for Widevine, which [could be extracted](https://gist.github.com/ruario/19a28d98d29d34ec9b184c42e5f8bf29) for use on other systems, but those are 32-bit only (`armhf`). Others have requested a similar [feature for Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1679354), noting that the missing ARM64 builds of Widevine prevent that.

Under Raspbian 32-bit you can install the `libwidevinecdm0` package, which provides Widevine support for Chromium.